# Seven thieves & diamonds riddle C program

Tags: c, puzzle

I recently wrote a C program for the following 'Seven thieves and diamonds' puzzle:

"There are seven thieves, They steal diamonds from a diamond merchant and run away in jungle. While running, night sets in and they decide to rest in the jungle When everybody’s sleeping, two of the best friends get up and decide to distribute the diamonds among themselves and run away. So they start distributing but find that one diamond was extra. So they decide to wake up 3rd one and divide the diamonds again …..only to their surprise they still find one diamond extra. So they decide to wake up fourth one. Again one diamond is spare. 5th woken up……still one extra. 6th still one extra. Now they wake up 7th and diamonds are distributed equally."

Although the logic is quite simple to understand, my program seems to be quite buggy. It only seems to run for the numbers 3, 5 and 7.

I am new to programming in general and I feel that my program is not very sophisticated:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int n,i,j,k; 
    int a[30]; 
    printf("Enter the number of thieves\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    i=n+1; 
    while(1) 
    { 
        j=2; 
        k=0; 
        while(j<n) 
        { 
            if(i%j == 1 && i%n==0) 
            { 
                a[k]=1; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                a[k]=0; 
            } 
            if(k==n-2) 
            { 
                k=0; 
            } 
            j++; 
            k++; 
        } 
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++) 
        { 
            if(a[j]==0) 
            { 
                break; 
            } 
            else if(j==n-3 && a[j] == 1) 
            { 
                printf("The number of diamonds = %d\n",i); 
                return; 
            } 
        } 
        i++; 
    } 
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me develop this code into something more nonspecific, such that it could return an output for all values of 'n.' Also, any feedback in general would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly? Also, what exactly is the program supposed to output? The minimum number of people the diamonds are divided among?

Comment: _There are seven thieves..._ then why you print `Enter the number of thieves`?

Comment: @adivk You can check that 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 + 1 is divisible by 7 and equal to 103.:)

Comment: @adivk I thinl you need to consider sets of prime numbers 2 ^ x * 3 ^ y * 5 ^ z + 1 and find the minimum value that is divisible by 7. For example the initial combination 2 ^ 2 * 3 ^ 1 * 5 ^ 1 + 1 is not divisible by 7.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a solution for number of thieves other than 3, 5, or 7 you've tried? The requirement that there be _exactly one_ diamond left over every time before they've woken everyone up is quite limiting, I'd imagine most numbers of thieves do not have a solution.

Comment: Do you wake someone up if it the diamonds simply do not divide evenly, or does it have to be exactly 1 left over? Non-divisibility seems more reasonable for this type of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very hard to follow, so I wrote my own code to debug this and your program although obscure and hard to follow is completely correct for valid inputs, you are just not handling all the cases very well thus you are in a while loop forever. Not every input will work for this problem only *prime numbers* will give you an answer for this problem so inputs like 2, 4, and 6 will not work so they need to be handled.

Here is a test comparing your outputs with the test I wrote for valid inputs.

```
#Of Theives   Your Code    Test Code
    3            3            3
    5            25           25
    7            301          301
    11           25201        25201
    13           83161        83161
```

You can write a quick function to test for this care of this like this:

```
int isPrime(int tmp)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i <= tmp/2; i++)
    {
        if(tmp % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Then you can check for valid inputs which numbers greater than 1 (because then there would not be enough thiefs for the story to happen) and prime like so:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int isPrime(int tmp)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i <= tmp/2; i++)
    {
        if(tmp % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}



int main() 
{ 
    int n,i,j,k; 
    int a[30]; 
    printf("Enter the number of thieves that is prime and greater than 1\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    i=n+1;
    if(isPrime(n) && n > 1)
    {
        while(1) 
        { 
            j=2; 
            k=0; 
            while(j<n) 
            { 
                if(i%j == 1 && i%n==0) 
                { 
                    a[k]=1; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    a[k]=0; 
                } 
                if(k==n-2) 
                { 
                    k=0; 
                } 
                j++; 
                k++; 
            } 
            for(j=0;j<n-1;j++) 
            { 
                if(a[j]==0) 
                { 
                    break; 
                } 
                else if(j==n-3 && a[j] == 1) 
                { 
                    printf("The number of diamonds = %d\n",i); 
                    return; 
                } 
            } 
            i++; 
        } 
    }
    else
    {
    printf("Input Invalid.\n"); 
    }
}
```

The code I wrote to test the riddle:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int isPrime(int tmp)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i <= tmp/2; i++)
    {
        if(tmp % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

long gcd(long a, long b) {
  if (b == 0) {
    return a;
  }
  else {
    return gcd(b, a % b);
  }
}

int main()
{
    int thieves, i;
    long diamonds, lcm = 1;
    printf("Enter the number of thieves that is prime and greater than 1:\n");
    scanf("%d",&thieves);

    if(isPrime(thieves) && thieves > 1)
    {
        for(i = 2;i < thieves;i++)
        {
                lcm = (lcm*i)/gcd(i,lcm);
        }

        i = 1;
        dimonds = lcm*i + 1;
        while(dimonds % thieves != 0)
        {
            dimonds = lcm*++i + 1;
        }
        printf("There are a minimum of diamonds is: %d\n",diamonds);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Input inv\n");

    }
}
```